# Non-existence of $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R}^5,\mathbf{R}^5)$ where $\operatorname{range} T=\operatorname{null} T$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Is the following Proof Correct?

*Theorem.* There does not exist a linear map $T:\mathbf{R}^5\to\mathbf{R}^5$ such that 
$$\operatorname{range} T=\operatorname{null} T$$
*Proof.* Assume on the contrary that that such a linear map exists, given that $\operatorname{range} T=\operatorname{null} T$  and since $\operatorname{null} T\leqslant \mathbf{R}^5$ it must be that $\dim \operatorname{range} T=m\in I = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ but
$$\forall j\in I(\dim \operatorname{range} T+\dim \operatorname{null} T = j+j=2j\neq\dim \mathbf{R}^5 =5)$$
defying the *rank-nullity-Theorem*.

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct, but you could just say "Suppose $T$ exists and has rank $k$.  Then $5 = rank T + nullity T = k + k = 2k$, and $5$ is not an even number."

Comment: Yes i concurr much more succinct